# R markdown plot enumerate

Tags: r, markdown

I use R markdown with LaTex to make homework solutions for a class I teach.  I typically set up the file so that I have the solutions within enumerate statements, and I am having a really hard time getting a plot to show up in one of the enumerates.  A sample markdown file is:

````
---
title: "Solutions"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{enumerate,graphicx}
geometry: margin=0.5in
output: pdf_document
---
\begin{enumerate}
%Problem 1%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \item 
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        ```{r, echo = FALSE}
        #Load some data
        ```
        \item The scatter plot of miles per gallon and cylinder is:
        ```{r, echo = FALSE}
        plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
        ```
        \item 
        \item 
        \item 
\end{enumerate}
\hrulefill
%Problem 2%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \item 
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item 
        \item 
        \item 
        \item 
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
````

This file does not knit, and it seems to have something to do with the fact that it is in an enumerate as far as I can tell.  Does anyone know how I could fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.